# net:err_connection_reset after loading php file completely

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a quite simple php page (PHP 5.5.35 on CentOS 5.11) that queries a MySQL database. The resulting page shows completely, including the footer I include as a final instruction, so the PHP script runs entirely without error.
Almost every images and js libraries are loaded. However, there are two elements that are never loaded, an image and a jquery library. Each time and with any browser, those elements generate a (in Chrome, for instance) :

> Failed to load ressource : net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

For testing purpose, I tried to delete those element from the page, ultimately, it is the favicon that can't be loaded. So it seems not to be those elements in particular. The connection seems to be reseted at some point between the PHP script completion and the page loading… and I don't have the beginning of any clue where I should start the troubleshoot.

Some other informations :

- Apache logs don't log anything !
- The other pages of the site works well
- The site works without any problem on my local machine (Mac OS X, PHP 5.5.35 too)
- Once the page is loaded, if I click any link on it, it shows a "Connection reseted" error page.

Does anybody have a clue, anything about where to start my search ? Thanks in advance, I am starting to desperate.

Answer (score 0):

It happened that after searching everywhere, the cause was simply that I was handling a lot of parameters through GET – too many of them. I changed the code for using POST and everything worked miraculously… Hope it may help someone, sometime !